# Sharepoint document version number not auto increment

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have a VSTO program which allow user to save document back to the sharepoint server with the following code:

```
Globals.ThisWorkbook.Saved = false;
Globals.ThisWorkbook.Save();
```

I have also implemented the ThisWorkbook_BeforeSave and ThisWorkbook_AfterSave. Both function were called when user click the VSTO button or the build-in save button on the top left corner.

[image: Save Button]

The problem is when user trigger the save action from VSTO program, the file version did not change in sharepoint, the orginal file was replaced with a newer file timestamp, while using the build in save button, the file version will increase by 0.1 (minor version)

Is there any setting problem related to the Office Upload Center can help?

Answer (score 0):

Click Library Settings.Under General Settings, click Versioning settings.Under the Content Approval section, choose Yes.Under the Document Version History section, choose "**Create major version**".